# Composer missing folder when I run 'composer install'

Tags: php, composer-php

I have this `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "simpleweb/SilverpopPHP" : "dev-master#3634c414c1e97f5e2a7cce80fa755befae4e62c1"
    }
}
```

and on this github repo I have the `EngagePod.php` file and an `Util` folder:
https://github.com/simpleweb/SilverpopPHP/tree/3634c414c1e97f5e2a7cce80fa755befae4e62c1/src/Silverpop

When I run `composer install`, the `Util` folder does not appear on the installed `vendor` folder within my project.

Does someone know why this could be happening?

Comment: Is this package in packagist, or do you have a `repositories` key defined to point to this Github repo?

Comment: I installed it using composer, I'm getting the files, its there, `vendor/simpleweb/silverpopphp/src/Silverpop`

Comment: I also installed it via composer, adding a `repositories` key pointing directly to this github repo. It all installs correctly with a PSR-0 directory layout.

Comment: I can also instantiate it with autoloading as `new Silverpop\EngagePod()` so it seems to work.

Comment: I have added the repositories directive (to go directly to github without packagist) and the Util folder is not there :(

Comment: Please post more of your `composer.json`. Using this configuration, I had no problems installing it whatsoever: https://gist.github.com/mberkowski/10483ced3a978bfbbc41

Comment: I am using this one now https://gist.github.com/romulodl/b0ee017a664b179f4266 I will try using the .git as per your example...

Comment: The repository URL in your composer.json is missing its .git extension! Your repo's correct https clone URL is `https://github.com/simpleweb/SilverpopPHP.git`

Comment: Same behavior :( The Util folder is not there. I am using Mac OSX 10.8.5

Comment: I'm not sure what other help I can offer. Using my very bare composer.json with either the ssh or https clone URLs to your repo, it installs successfully in `vendor/simpleweb/silverpopphp/src/Silverpop/`

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts and a long discussion in the comments with Michael Berkowski I could solve my issue by adding the option `--prefer-dist` which will download and not clone from github.

It fixed the issue but actually I still don't know why this is happening.